# Select specific filenames from an array of filenames containing a date in the name

Tags: matlab, octave

If I have a group of .wav files and Im trying to pick only month wise or do daily/only night psd(power spectral density) averages etc or choose files belonging to a month how to go about? The following are first 10 .wav files in a .txt file that are read into matlab code-

```
AMAR168.1.20150823T200235Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T201040Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T201845Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T202650Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T203455Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T204300Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T205105Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T205910Z.wav
AMAR168.1.20150823T210715Z.wav
```

yyyymmddTHHMMSSZ.wav is part of the format to get sense of some parameters.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi kanachi, I will edit your title if you don't mind, to make it more relevant to your problem. Let me know if this is not what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific.
Do all files always start with "AMAR168.1." for instance?

Anyway, here's a general approach to get you started:

```
AllFilenames = fileread ('filenames.dat');
FileNames    = strsplit (AllFilenames, '\n');
for i = FileNames                                          
  if ~isempty (strfind (i{:}, '20150823')); disp(i{:}); end
end
```

Your filename examples aren't very useful because they all have the same date, but, anyway, you get the point.

Alternatively, if the filenames ***always*** have the same format and size, you could do, e.g.:

```
AllFilenames   = fileread ('filenames.dat');              
AllFilenames   = strvcat (strsplit (AllFilenames, '\n'));
LogicalIndices = categorical (cellstr (AllFilenames(:,15:16))) == '08';
```

to obtain all rows where the month is '08' for instance. *This assumes that the month is always at position 15 to 16 in the string*

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes all my files start with AMAR168.1